# MySQL SELECT RANDOM IF COUNT OF WORDS

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where one of the columns contains text, for which I count the words:

```
SELECT SUM( LENGTH(`text`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`text`, ' ', ''))+1) AS length 
FROM tblParadigm WHERE `uuid`=$uuid;
```

So that I can filter rows which have below or above a certain count of words.
Now I can select random rows from this table, using:

```
SELECT `uuid` FROM tblParadigm  ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 10;
```

My Question is, how can I combine those two, in order to select 10 random rows, which have a word count of less than `$count`?

Do I need a `JOIN` or an `IF`? I would prefer to do this in MySQL rather than PHP.

Comment: MySQL RAND is a very bad operator, it is top heavy and quite processor intensive and not even a very good random generator. Using it on tables that are any larger than approx a hundred lines will be very expensive in time and processor power. Try and avoid using the MySQL RAND function if there are more efficient ways of doing this

Comment: It would seem you just need to select one more column - the uuid - and add an extra condition; both `SELECT`'s are from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the MySQL HAVING clause at the end of your first query.

```
Having length < 5
```

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry about that.